# How to handle actions from different parts complex ViewModels in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a complex form, with hierarchy of view models and I am wondering how to structure the code so that my controller will not contain handlers for all actions.

Here is a simplified example:
[image: Sample view for a complex ViewModel]
with the corresponding ViewModel:

```
public class MyPageViewModel
{
   public List<TabViewModel> Tabs {get; set; }
   public CustomerViewModel Customer;
}

public class TabViewModel
{
    public string DisplayLabel { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}

class CustomerViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}  

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

I do know how to separate rendering of each part of the page in separate components: I am using `@Html.EditorFor` and `@Html.DisplayFor` and have a separate view for each part of the model (indicated by the red rectangles on the picture above).  This works quite nice. Parts of the ViewModel (for example `TabViewModel` class) can also be re-used on other pages.

I am having problems with event handling logic. There are quite few actions that can be performed on this page (indicated with blue background). One possibility would be to use multiple FORM tags  – each for one red rectangle on picture above. Each form would have a different action URL and would be handled by a different controller.  But when using this approach, I could lose same data. For example: if the user changes First Name and then hits the Remove Address button the First Name would not be POSTed back to the server and the change would be lost.

This leaves me with one form for the whole page. That means that all actions should be processed by a single controller class. I really do not like this approach, because:

- I’ll end up with big, fat controller containing action handling code for all buttons
- Or I’ll have a big switch statement within my controller, which would identify the action, locate separate class, that know how to handle the action and then delegate the  processing to it (yuck! This sound like writing windows messages event handling code in 1990s – WindowProc)

I’ve read about Html.ActionFor which enables you to call a separate controller from a View, but I do not think this is good approach either (it happens while view is being rendered, which  is not OK).

So, to sum up, here’s the question again: **Is there a way to handle the actions/events triggered from different parts of complex view model in such a way that I will not end up with a mess in my controller?** What are the best practices for a real-life applications (not 101 CRUD examples that are generated by Visual studio scaffolding )

**UPDATE:** Please note that this is just a simplified example - in the reality, the view model is much more complex and there are many more actions, that can be performed. I am asking about a general approach for structuring the code in controller (or moving it to separate classes) in ASP.NET MVC application. The WebForms provided user controls, which enabled us to encapsulate both the View part (ASCX) and the event handlers. MVC has a good solution for encapsulating the views and I am trying to find the right way to structure the logic/event handlers.

Comment: For your example, I'd say you need a "Save" button for the first name/name modification if you want to use the multiple controller/form approach.

Comment: With jQuery and Ajax this would be simple enough since the page would not refresh when posting certain data, but obviously this would not scale back well for older/less compatible browsers - but that may be the price you have to pay

Comment: @MikeSW: I've taken a rather deep look at angualrjs. It is very good framework, but for now I have decided not to use it, since it represents too strastic change from methods and tools I am currenlty using.

Comment: @Charleh, thanks, but I am not asking how to solve the page refresh (we are already using Ajax).  I am asking on how to structure the code on the server.

Comment: Still don't see why this is an issue - if you click 'remove address' on an address, you just send a remove address command to whichever controller you want, then refresh the part of the page that contains the address info (or just do it in JS). The user doesn't lose the 'name' data because you don't refresh that part of the page... am I wrong? jQuery.ajax allows you to write a response back to a certain area of the page - in fact you could call a controller that doesn't return any particular page data and on success of the ajax call refresh by calling the current URL again...there are options

Comment: This would be painful. Lets assume that you used a single controller, and user deleting an address. How could you know which row's deleting?  Obviously you need to keep the ID of address in hidden field with JavaScript and On the server side, you'll delete it with hidden ID. And you say, that is complex than this example. You should consider to split forms (IMO just use ajax).

Answer (score 0):

I would add a "Save" button for the customer data fieldset and save/post all of the customer data when the user hits the Save button. This way on your Edit Post Action you will only use `CustomerViewModel`.

"Add new address" and "Remove this address" will add and remove the html needed for `Address` with javascript.

"Search for existing customer" and "Select from external DB" can show a pop up with data needed for their respectful sections in the form. Use Ajax to get the data.

This way you will have a simple Edit Post Action for the CustomerData fieldset, 2 Actions for displaying the data in in pop ups, and some javascript for manipulating the addresses section.

Comment: Thanks, but the Save button would ruin user experience. I cannot require the user to click additional button just because I have problems with structuring the code on the server.

Comment: @matra how do you save changes in the customer data fieldset if you're not using a save button?

Comment: The changes to customer should be saved even if "Remove this address" button is clicked or "History" tab is selected. This mean, that they must be part of the each request, that is posted to the server.

Comment: @matra I think that's why it is so complicated to make all of this work. Since you want to separate your views logic, you should only post data that is related to the view or form that it belongs to, otherwise you'll indeed end up with a big controller handling everything. Also, I don't think that modifying user data without having to click a button is a good thing, that could lead to errors since the user could think that data wasn't modified since he didn't click anywhere

Comment: @ppetrov: Imagine user of clasic Wnidows Applciation. Wouldn't he be surprised when he removes customer address and loses changes that he made to customer name. Another example: do you loose the content of your To: field when you remove an attachment while composing an email in gmail.com? The user does not care weather the events are server or client side and which fields are contained in which FORM tag.

Comment: @matra I see your point. But I don't see why he would lose the changes made to customer name if you're updating the adresses using ajax calls. Also when do you save all the modifications? Even in a windows forms application you have a "save" or "commit" button to save all the changes you have made... Also  when do you do a postback? Does changing the tab makes a postback?

Comment: Yes, changing a tab does a postback. Saving is implicit (for example when user changes tab). Ajax that posts back one red area on the picture could be one solution, but is problematic if action triggered by one part of GUI (for exampleDeleteAddress) changes other part of the GUI (for example  Total address count that could be displayed at the top of customer data). Or in general: it is problematic when separate views display the same information (usually in different forms - one view in aggregated form, the other as details).